# Anotar.Serilog [LogToErrorOnException] add catch

Tags: c#, .net, exception, serilog

I am looking for solution how I can log with catch.
[LogToErrorOnException] is good, but I want same without raising up the exception.
Something like [CatchAndLogToErrorOnException] which will do following for linked method:

```
void TestMethod()
{ 
  try 
  {
    // original code of method here
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    LogTo.Error(e, "");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine Anotar.Fody with SwallowExceptions.Fody:

https://github.com/duaneedwards/SwallowExceptions#working-alongside-other-fody-plugins

Comment: can't link (library reference can't be found). looks like it is created for more newer .NET

Answer (score 0):

This is [not supported](https://github.com/Fody/Anotar/issues/82) by [`Anotar.Fody`](https://github.com/Fody/Anotar) for any of the logger implementations (not just Serilog).

You'll have to implement your own version of the [`OnExceptionProcessor`](https://github.com/Fody/Anotar/blob/master/Serilog/Anotar.Serilog.Fody/OnExceptionProcessor.cs#L154), and skip re-throwing the exception.

Comment: means I need to use a separate custom library for this, it is not a good solution for me